# Edge Chromium xlsm issue

Tags: html, sharepoint-2010, microsoft-edge, xlsm

On a web application we manage, there is an issue only present in Edge Chromium. There is a button to download a file: an Excel macro file. When clicking the button in Edge, the file is opened in Excel. However, the login page of the webapplication appears in the XLSM file in Excel, instead of opening the xlsm file itself. In Google Chrome, the file is not opened, but downloaded first and when clicking open, we get the wanted behaviour.

This is the code behind the button (confidential data replaced by XXX):

`<input type="submit" onclick="redirectToNavUrlGA('https://XXX.xlsm','XXX','XXX','XXXXXX'); return false;" value="XXXXXX">`

When calling the URL directly in a cache cleared-Edge browser, the login page appears in browser and the file is downloaded correctly. Only when you are already logged in the to application, the issue is present. But users will always be logged in already, so not a good workaround.

The URL is using reverse proxy to point to a Sharepoint 2010 site to download the file. I've read some issues with Edge Chromium and SP 2010, is this maybe the cause of the issue?
Do you have any other ideas that could be causing this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I think the main problem is the compatibility issue between SharePoint 2010 and Edge. The Edge browser is not included in [**SharePoint 2010 browser support**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-foundation-2010/cc288142(v=office.14)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#browser-support-matrix), and even Edge IE 11 mode is not supported. So I suggest that you can use a supported browser.